# PayPal doesn't send me all fields to return url

Tags: php, paypal

I've setup subscribe form for PayPal.

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/success/">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
...
```

Then I make a payment in PP Sandbox and click to "Return to Merchant" button.

I expect:

all transaction data in `$_POST`, such `txn_type` and so on

I get:

```
[merchantReturn_x] => Return To Merchant
[auth] =>qQJeJB06AAvD3o1Q5_7MOb6oCrg7OLBbQnYJOLBn0x4xAjnRwG4wORijts5Bo5gYPGMAid1eC3R9m9FYDD2
[form_charset] => UTF-8
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

those data will not be posterd to that URL ... search the manual for IPN ( Instant Payment Notification ). Basicly there is another script that receives those parameters.

Comment: hm, here (https://ppmts.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/ppdts.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=309) is another information.

Comment: did u check the settings described there for the POST method ? also make sure you verify that information back to paypal as shown in their example